# Video Compression using LightCompressor is not working

Tags: android, video, video-compression

I am trying to compress a video that is recorded by a mobile camera. For that purpose, I am using the below library:

https://github.com/AbedElazizShe/LightCompressor

I am passing the captured video path and destination path. I can see it is reaching to onSuccess() method. But I can't find any compressed video on my destination path.

```
     @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.d("Testing", "ACTIVITY REQUEST CODE " + requestCode);
        switch (requestCode) {

            case VIDEO_CAPTURE:
                Log.d("Testing", "RESULT CODE " + resultCode);
                if (data != null && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                    Uri videoUri = data.getData();

                    File destinationPath = new File(String.valueOf(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)));
                    File file = new File(destinationPath.getAbsolutePath());

                    Log.d("Testing", "Video Source Path::  "+currentVideoPath);
                    Log.d("Testing", "Video destination Path::  "+file.toString());
                    VideoCompressor.start(currentVideoPath, file.toString(), new CompressionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onStart() {
                        // Compression start
                        Log.d("Testing", "compressed onStart  ");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        // On Compression success
                       Log.d("Testing", "compressed file size ");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(String failureMessage) {
                        // On Failure
                        Log.d("Testing", "compressed onFailure  ");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(float v) {
                        Log.d("Testing", "Progress::  ");
                        // Update UI with progress value
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled() {
                        // On Cancelled
                        Log.d("Testing", "compressed onCancelled  ");
                    }
                }, VideoQuality.HIGH, true, true);

                }else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Video recording cancelled.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to record video",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;

}
```

When I check the log, is I am getting:

Video Source Path::

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.app.powerconsent/files/Pictures/101_20210213_194206.mp4
2021-02-13 19:42:20.287 18288-18288/com.app.powerconsent D/Testing: Video destination Path::  /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.app.powerconsent/files/Download
2021-02-13 19:42:20.394 18288-18288/com.app.powerconsent D/Testing: compressed onStart  
2021-02-13 19:42:20.567 18288-18288/com.app.powerconsent D/Testing: compressed file size
```

Can someone point if is there anything going wrong? Do I need to call something using a background task?

Answer (score 0):

Your destination path should point to a file and not a folder.